# Biblatex labelprefix with counter

Tags: biblatex, labels, counters

I am writing a proposal and I need to split my bibliography into (1) own published papers, (2) own unpublished papers, and (3) other references

Parts (1) and (2) are limited to 10 references and I need to tag and number them (say 0-9) in the following way:

My publications

[MY0:Mys21] Myself. “A work of mine”. In: (2021).

[MY1:Mys22a] Myself. “A work of mine”. In: (2022).

My unpublished work

[MY2:Mys22b]  Myself. “A work of mine”. In: (2022).

References

[Som12] Person Some random. “Doing random things”. In: (2012).

[Som18] Author Some other. “Doing other things”. In: (2018).

I found out how to include the prefix "MY:" but I don't know how to include the numbering "MY0:", "MY1:", "MY2:" etc. into the prefix. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=none,backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
      @article{A1,
        author = {Myself},
        year = {2021},
        title = {A work of mine},
        keywords={minepub}
      }
      @article{A2,
        author = {Myself},
        year = {2022},
        title = {A work of mine},
        _shorthand = {XX},
        keywords={minepub}
      }
      @article{A3,
        author = {Myself},
        year = {2022},
        title = {A work of mine},
        _shorthand = {XX},
        keywords={mineunpub}
      }
      @article{B3,
        author = {Some random, Person},
        year = {2012},
        title = {Doing random things}
      }
      @article{B4,
        author = {Some other, Author},
        year = {2018},
        title = {Doing other things}
      }
  \end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
These are my published works, \cite{A1,A2}. This is some unpublished work of mine, \cite{A3}. This is another one \cite{B3}, this as well, \cite{B4}, while this is one of mine and that of this other person \cite{A1,B3}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={MY:}]
\printbibliography[title={My publications},keyword=minepub]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={MY:}]
\printbibliography[title={My unpublished work},keyword=mineunpub]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=minepub,notkeyword=mineunpub]

\end{document}
```

Edit:

I found a workaround that is not quite what I was hoping for but I think it meets the requirements of numbering the list of own publications. It uses a customized bibenvironment, which is used only in bibliography sections (1) and (2) to enumerate using a counter. The other references (3) use the default environment without a counter:

```
\newcounter{refs}
\setcounter{refs}{1}
\defbibenvironment{mybib}
  {\list
     {\therefs. \printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \addtolength{\labelwidth}{14pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item\stepcounter{refs}}

...

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={MY:}]
\printbibliography[env=mybib,title={My publications},keyword=minepub]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={MY:}]
\printbibliography[env=mybib,title={My unpublished work},keyword=mineunpub]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix={}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=minepub,notkeyword=mineunpub]
```

The result is:
My publications

1. [MY:Mys21] Myself. “A work of mine”. In: (2021).
2. [MY:Mys22a] Myself. “A work of mine”. In: (2022).

My unpublished work

3. [MY:Mys22b] Myself. “A work of mine”. In: (2022).

References

[Som12] Person Some random. “Doing random things”. In: (2012).

[Som18] Author Some other. “Doing other things”. In: (2018).